# How to read text from a dat file without it showing hexadecimals? C++

Tags: c++, file, hex

I'm writing a program where i ask a user to input a **username** and **password** and then its stored in a `dat file`. Then its supposed to output the username and password but it just give me hexadecimals such as `0x9ffd18`. here the code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
fstream myfile;
myfile.open ("password.dat"); 
string username;
string password;
cout << "This is being saved to a file" << endl;
cout << "Please enter your username" << endl;
getline (cin, username);
myfile << username;
cout << "Please enter your password" << endl;
getline (cin, password);
myfile << password;
cout << myfile << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> cout << myfile << endl;
> ```

doesn't output what you have been writing to your file, but a `void*` interpretation of `myfile`'s address, which is printed as hex value by default.

You need to close your file (or `seekg()` to the starting position), open it again, and read the values as they were written.

Comment: No, you can do myfile.seekg to the beginning and do a "myfile >>" to a variable, and the print this value.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to solve the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  fstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("password.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
  string username;
  string password;
  cout << "This is being saved to a file" << endl;
  cout << "Please enter your username" << endl;
  getline (cin, username);
  myfile << username;
  cout << "Please enter your password" << endl;
  getline (cin, password);
  myfile << password;
  char data[100];
  myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);
  myfile >> data;
  cout << "Output: " << endl;
  cout << data << endl;
  myfile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here. One is the simple act of rewinding the file and reading back the contents. Another (probably more important, at least in the long term) is to write the file in a way that it can be read back unambiguously.

The problem right now is that you write the user name and password with nothing to define where one ends and the other starts. The most obvious candidate would be a new-line. You read both in using `getline`, which stops reading at a new-line, so we know neither can contain a new-line.

Other than that, I'd `#include <string>` since you're using `std::string`, and get rid of the `using namespace std;` and the `endl`s (almost always mistakes). The result might look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::fstream myfile("password.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);

    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::cout << "Please enter your username: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, username);
    myfile << username << '\n';
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter your password: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, password);
    myfile << password;

    myfile.seekg(0);

    std::string read_back_user_name;
    std::string read_back_password;

    std::getline(myfile, read_back_user_name);
    std::getline(myfile, read_back_password);

    std::cout << "The user name is: " << read_back_user_name << "\n";
    std::cout << "The password is: " << read_back_password << "\n";
}
```

If you really want to just copy the entire content of the file to cout, you can do something like this:

```
    myfile.seekg(0);

    cout << myfile.rdbuf();
```

Answer (score -1):

You print not the data you inputed to file, but the `std::fstream` object converted to address. To fix that, use method `rdbuf()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("password.dat"); //open for input
    string username;
    string password;
    cout << "This is being saved to a file" << endl;
    getline (cin, username);
    myfile << username; //input first string
    cout << "Please enter your password" << endl;
    getline (cin, password);
    myfile << password; //input second string
    myfile.close(); //close so data is sent from buffer
    myfile.open("password.dat"); //open for output
    cout << "Your file: " << myfile.rdbuf() << endl; //print all characterf from file
    myfile.close();

}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not the `fstream` address, but the output of its `operator void*`, which is a null pointer if `fail()` returns true, and some other unspecified value otherwise.

Comment: @Metteo Italia: yeah, true